# Hibernate mapping throws class not found exception

Tags: sql-server-2008, hibernate-mapping, tapestry

I've been trying to start up Tapestry with Hibernate through SQL Server 2008. I followed the tapestry and hibernate guide at the start, but when I got to the mapping part, I got this class not found exception, that further throws could not parse mapping document from resource exception, and so far I could not find a solution for this.
This is the mapping file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
 "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
 <hibernate-mapping>
 <class name="com.example.tutorial.entities.Address.java" table="address">

        <id name="id">          
            <column name="id"/>
            <generator class="increment"/>
        </id>
    <property name="honorific" type="java.lang.String"/>
    <property name="firstName" type="java.lang.String"/>
    <property name="lastName" type="java.lang.String"/>
    <property name="street1" type="java.lang.String"/>
    <property name="street2" type="java.lang.String"/>
    <property name="city" type="java.lang.String"/>
    <property name="state" type="java.lang.String"/>
    <property name="zip" type="java.lang.String"/>
    <property name="email" type="java.lang.String"/>
    <property name="phone" type="java.lang.Integer"/>       
</class>
```

and this is the hibernate.cfg.xml:

```xml
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:sqlserver://localhost/testdb;integratedSecurity=true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">not required</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password"></property>
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.format_sql">true</property>
    <mapping resource="mappings/hibernate.hbm.xml" />
</session-factory>
```

This is the full error trace:
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B0_KI_Lyv76_b05WTkZxVG1XLTA/edit?usp=sharing

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: use `com.example.tutorial.entities.Address` instead of `com.example.tutorial.entities.Address.java` in your mapping file.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that got things running again. This has been bugging me since yesterday, couldn't realize what I was doing wrong.